# VMware player and ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-player, linux-kernel

I'm trying to run VMware player 3.1.4 on the latest ubuntu (11.04), but it fails to launch saying:

`Kernel Headers for generic pae not found.

 C header files matching your running kernel were not found.  Refer to your distribution's documentation for installation instructions.`

But when I type

`mamluck@mamluck:~$ uname -r

2.6.38-8-generic-pae`

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to install the kernel headers:
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic-pae`.

More info [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic-pae)

Good luck!

Comment: I already did that but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Why it fails? No Internet connection? Repositories setup? Error message?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Do a reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-`uname -r`
```